# How to show that composition is not in general commutative on $\text{Funct}(X, X)$?

Tags: functions, binary-operations

This is Exercise 3 from page 27 of *Analysis I* by Amann and Escher. I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1038916/composition-of-two-functions-is-not-commutative/1038948#1038948) question by searching, but I don't understand the top answer, particularly the part about choosing $g(f(x))$ independently of $g(x)$. I'm not sure if it answers my question.

**Exercise:**

> Show that composition $\circ$ is not, in general, a commutative
> operation on $\text{Funct}(X, X)$.

($\text{Funct}(X, X)$ is the set of all functions from $X$ to $X$.)

**Comments:**

Showing that something is not true "in general" is confusing. I feel that the wording of the question suggests that it's not enough to find a counterexample. Is this perhaps a translation issue? (I think this book was originally written in German.)

If it helps at all, Example 4.9 on page 26 says in part, "...composition is an associative operation on $\text{Funct}(X, X)$. It may not be commutative (see Exercise 3)."

It's not hard to show that two different constant functions will not commute. Is that satisfactory? I don't know.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: To show that something is not true in general, it suffices to find a counterexample. (Note that in general it may be not necessary: there are ways to show that a counterexample exists, without presenting it).

Comment: Yes: to show that composition of functions is not commutative "in general", it certainly suffices to find one example of functions that do not commute. Another phrase people might use is that composition is not "necessarily" commutative. Using either of these qualifiers is probably intended to reassure the reader that occasionally functions might commute, although that's logically unnecessary.

Comment: I would think that "in general" is only meant to say that for *some* cases composition does commute. The only other meaning that I can think of is that composition "almost never" commutes (in the sense that there might be some measure under which the commutative examples are negligible).

Comment: I appreciate the help. I will assume that the authors are asking for a counterexample. The authors don't discuss measure theory until about 800 pages from now, so that can't be the intended meaning.